# $Var(a_1X^2 + a_2X) > 0$ whenever $(a_1 , a_2) \neq 0$ where $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Say I have $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. I would like to show

$$
Var(a_1X^2 + a_2X) > 0 
$$

only except when $a_1 = a_2 = 0$

**My attempt**

$$
Var(a_1X^2 + a_2X) = Var(a_1 (X+a_2/(2a_1))^2
$$

where $X+a_2/(2a_1)$ follows scaled noncentral $\chi^2$. But I can't proceed.

Comment: Note that by the definition of variance, it is non-negative. It equals to zero if and only if the underlying random variable is degenerate - equal to a constant almost surely. It is trivial to check the case for $a_1 = a_2 = 0$. Suppose there exist $(a_1, a_2) \neq (0, 0)$ such that the variance is $0$. Then you can argue that a quadratic polynomial equation has at most two real roots, but the support of a normal random variable is uncountable. So there is a contradiction.

Comment: Just add as a supplement and better presentation: The above argument says $a_1X^2 + a_2X + a_3 = 0$ almost surely. Note that the support of a normal random variable is the whole real number. So we have $a_1x^2 + a_2x + a_3 \equiv 0$ and by comparing coefficient, $a_1 = a_2 = 0$.